# cURL command line login (bash)

Tags: php, linux, bash, curl

I have a bash script on a cronjob.

```
do 
curl -d "test=working" https:/mysite.com/test
echo "done" 
done
```

Right now, it just makes a post request on my site.

But now I want to make a post request in a members only area 2 times

So how can I login keep the session, and post 2 times?
I can't test this as I'm on my phone for a while but it's been bugging me.

```
do 
curl -d "uname=a&pass=b" https:/mysite.com/login
for run in {1..2}
do
curl -d "test=working" https:/mysite.com/memberarea
echo "done" 
done
```

Would this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the cookies:

```
curl -b cookies.txt -c cookies.txt -e website.com -d 'xx=yy' http://website.com/path/to/resource
```

The `-b(--cookie)` means use the cookie from cookies.txt,
and the `-c(--cokie-jar)` means dumps the cookie to cookies.txt.

so always add the two option when use `curl` in your script and so that you can keep the session.

FYI:

```
do 
curl -b cookies.txt -c cookies.txt -e mysite.com -d "uname=a&pass=b" https:/mysite.com/login
for run in {1..2}
do
curl -b cookies.txt -c cookies.txt -e mysite.com -d "test=working" https:/mysite.com/memberarea
echo "done" 
done
```

Answer (score 1):

If your website uses cookie for keeping authenticated session, you can use `--cookie name=data` to pass the authentication username and password and use `--cookie-jar <filename>` to store the cookie.